# best/correct way to add value="" to a <button>

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've been creating buttons in two ways:

```
<button class="....>NAME</button>
```

and

```
<div class="btn-group....
     <label class="btn...><input>NAME</input></label>
     <label...
</div>
```

Question is, if I were to add a value to a button (to be manipulated on pressing the button), where /should/ I do that? In the label, the input, or use the < button> method? I'm ignorant, I know.

Comment: Note that while the `.btn` class may make that `<input>` _look_ like a button, it will function like a text input unless the `type="button"` attribute is added.

Comment: thanks guys, good stuff

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the value you want to modify. If you just want to change the Text on the button, you can use both by editing the innerHTML-Value of the Element the text is in via JavaScript. This would be in this cases the  and the  If you want to modify things like an onClick-Event I'd prefer to use the  method, but it's possible with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Only `<button>` is a real button.

The other is a link styled to look like a button.